# Why aren't NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver working as expected here?

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedarchiver

I've been working on a project where I need to write some objects to disk and then get them back again later. I was using `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to do the writing and reading, making sure that my custom classes conformed to `NSCoding`. It wasn't working and so, after a long time attempting to debug it and searching the Web, I've decided to isolate the problem.

Could someone please tell me why this code doesn't do what I expect it to do? It's probably obvious, but after staring at it for many hours I still can't work it out.

I've got a view controller defined in `Main.storyboard` with a `UILabel`, a `UITextField` and a `UIButton`. The idea is that the user can type something in, press the 'Post' button, and the label will display what they have entered. Each time the user enters something I want it to be written to disk so that if the app is quit and the view is loaded again, the message is brought back and displayed by the label.

At the moment, the label displays what the user has entered, but if I quit the app and reopen it, the label just says 'Your message here' which is the string I've assigned it in the storyboard.

I have a feeling that it might be something to do with the `unarchiveObject(withFile:)` call and/or the typecast to `String` because I read somewhere that since Swift 3, value types must be unarchived by using their own method (e.g. `unarchiveBool(withFile:)`), although there appears to be no such method for `String`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var outputLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textBox: UITextField!

    var filePath: URL!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        filePath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("message")

        // Load message
        if let loadedMessage = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: filePath.absoluteString) as? String {
            outputLabel.text = loadedMessage
        }
    }

    @IBAction func textFieldDoneEditing(_ sender: UITextField) {
        sender.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    @IBAction func postButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        outputLabel.text = textBox.text
        textBox.text = ""

        let str = outputLabel.text!

        // Save message      
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: str)
        do {
            try data.write(to: filePath)
        } catch {
            print("Couldn't write file.")
        }
    }
}
```

---

Okay, @gkchristopher has pointed out that `NSCoder` can't work directly with `String` so I should wrap my data in a class that conforms to `NSCoding`. So here's a small class that attempts to do that:

```
class DataThing: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var message: String!

    init(withMessage message: String) {
        self.message = message
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init(withMessage: aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "message") as! String)
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(message, forKey: "message")
    }
}
```

I can write data fine using this class:

```
let dataThing = DataThing(withMessage: str)

        // Save message
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dataThing)
        do {
            try data.write(to: filePath)
        } catch {
            print("couldn't write file.")
        }
```

However, reading still doesn't work:

```
if let loadedData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: filePath.absoluteString) as? DataThing {
            outputLabel.text = loadedData.message
}
```

Have I misinterpreted 'Wrap your data in a class'?

Comment: Have you stepped through with the debugger?

Comment: Yes. It seems to be writing the data out successfully (no exception thrown), but when I rebuild and run the app the `loadedMessage` string has 'unable to read data' written next to it in the local variables viewer. Based on that, I think there is either a problem with the way that data is being written (such that it can't be read later), or there is simply a problem with reading it.

Comment: I've now set `filePath` to `URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/Xander/Desktop") .appendingPathComponent("message")` to see what happens if I attempt to write straight to my desktop. It works, and the file appears to contain data. Still failing to unarchive it though...

Comment: You don't really need to create your own data type. Just read and write the data directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer:

Change `filePath.absoluteString` to `filePath.path`.

Original answer:

`NSCoder` may not work directly with a Swift struct, such as `String`. You'll need to wrap your data in a class and conform to `NSCoding` in order to use `NSKeyedArchiver`.

Example:

```
let file = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("message")
let dataThing = DataThing(withMessage: "Boo")
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(dataThing, toFile: file.path)

let retrieved = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: file.path)

dump(retrieved)
```

Comment: That class is very unreadable in the comments but I'm not sure where else to post this addition...

Comment: @xander You can edit your question to add updated information.

Comment: @Abizern I know, I just didn't think it made sense to do that... I will now though.

Comment: Also, you should try using `filePath.path` instead of `filePath.absoluteString`. These two are different in this case.

Comment: Yes! That's what I just did and it now works. Although after making this change I no longer need to use my `DataThing` class — I can just archive the string directly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create your own struct, You don't even need an Archiver/Unarchiver for a simple string. A String can be read from and written to Data directly.

Try rewriting your code to look like this.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    lazy var fileURL: URL = {
        do {
            var url = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            url.appendPathComponent("message")
            return url
        } catch {
            fatalError("Cannot create storage file")
        }
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        do {
            let message = try String(contentsOf: fileURL)
            label.text = message

        } catch {
            label.text = "No message available"
        }
    }

    @IBAction func post(_ sender: UIButton) {
        label.text = textField.text

        guard
            let text = textField.text,
            let data = text.data(using: .utf8),
            text != ""
            else { return }

        do {
            try data.write(to: fileURL)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        textField.text = ""
    }

}
```

I've been a bit fast and loose with the errors, you can handle them as specific to your application.

Comment: I thought so. It would make sense for all child objects to conform to `NSCoding`, not just the root object. And in that case, wrapping a non-conforming type (`String`) in a conforming type (`DataThing`) wouldn't seem to help.

Comment: For simple structs, you can just create a dictionary representation and read and write to plists. For anything more complicated, there are other forms of persistence that might be more suitable (Core Data, Realm, Mantle, etc)